Blender 4.2.3 uses Python to determine which collections are selected and get selected Collections from Python
I'm use blender 4.2.3.
How can I find out which collections are selected and select multiple collections using a script.
I've already tried it with:

bpy.context.layer_collection
bpy.context.layer_collection.children
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.children
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection


but they're all readonly.
With bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.[...] you only get the collection you last clicked on.
But I need a list of all the selected collections.
I managed to do all of this with objects but not with collections.
I've only found outdated examples on the internet.
Does anyone have any ideas what else I could try?

This answer seems to work for me in Blender 4.3.
